# How to sync (bi-directional) a field between service cloud and marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud, data-synchronization

Just wondering if there is a way or non-formal way to sync a field between SFMC and SFSC?
I researched and came across data streams but it is a one way sync between service cloud to marketing cloud when I need it synced between both clouds.

If not - is there a way to do an update action to update the fields when a change has been made on either clouds?

Answer (score 6):

There is no possibility of using the native connector for performing a two-way sync. Data from your Sales/Service Cloud will only be synced to Synchronised Data Extensions in Marketing Cloud. You have, however, few options for updating data in the opposite direction:

1. Use AmpScript function [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm) to select and update a record
2. Use [Object Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_object_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) in Journey Builder
3. Use [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/) together with SSJS, to perform an update of multiple records from Automation Studio.

Please be more specific and provide more context for a more tailored advice.